# vue webpacker configuration error

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-2

I was using Vue.js Webpacker integration with Rails 5.2.1. Unfortunately, I'm getting the error `Webpacker can't find public.css in /Users/jt/repos/embers2/public/packs/manifest.json` with a list of causes. I have googled the error message but it's unclear what is going on. The .css file is not in the manifest file but my embedded styles in my .vue files were working. Any ideas how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: seems like more of webpacker issue than webpack/vue

Answer (score 1):

The end of the error there might be hinting at the cause.

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'public' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'public' %>
```

Do you actually have a public.css file in your `app\javascript\src` folder?  More info about that in the [usage section](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#usage) of Webpacker

Comment: thx - so it's a vue.js app. My understanding is that vue-loader should be pulling the styles from vue components. So, no, I don't have a /app/javascript/src folder.  It had been working fine but was trying to get ./webpack-dev-server working as compiles were ~10 to 20 seconds.

Comment: I did reinstall webpacker and perhaps that mangled things to remove my vue-loader prefs. I'm no expert (obviously) at this but had been working fine for a few months. Let me dig through the webpacker docs again.

Comment: The pack tags are specific to webpacker itself, its using vue-loader behind the scenes.  Little bit of info about that [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/css.md#using-css-with-vue-loader).  That said - not having the file there isn't necessarily the cause of this.  I have the stylesheet_pack_tag without a corresponding css file and Webpacker doesn't seem to care.